# How do I properly configure a Golang gorilla/pat router to serve static asset folders?

Tags: css, go, gorilla

I have two html files that are parsed as follows:

```
var LoginTemplate = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
    "views/_base.html",
    "views/login.html",
))
```

And executed as such:

```
func LoginFormHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ctx *models.Context) error {
    err := LoginTemplate.Execute(w, ctx)

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 404)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Here are the contents of _base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">

      <title>{{ template "title" . }}</title>

      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      {{ template "styles" . }}
      {{ template "scripts" . }}
  </head>

  {{ template "content" . }}

</html>
```

The templates specified above are all defined in login.html.  For example, "styles" wraps all of my CSS links, etc. In my main function, I use a gorilla/pat router to handle several page requests to the server.  Additionally, I want to serve my static assets folders like this:

```
router.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets/"))))

  if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+settings.Server.Port, router); err != nil {
        panic(err)
  }
```

However, upon building and running my program, then navigating to local host, I see that none of the CSS or js appears to be rendering.  My css and js folders are in this tree:

> ROOT/
>
> > assets/
> >
> > > css/
> > >       js/

Comment: I have tried passing the string argument "assets" to http.Dir as well.

Comment: Are you running your program from the same directory as your `assets/` folder exists in? Specifically, you should be doing `go build & ./<programname>` instead of `go run main.go` (which will run it from a temp dir)

Comment: Yes, my main function resides in a file called femp.go, which is located in the same directory as assets/.  I do `go build` then (on my Windows machine) `femp.exe --settings=settings.xml`, where settings is a custom flag that unmarshals an xml file containing server and db specs.

Comment: @bama_programmer can you show your template scripts